# Стоит ли заменять анонимную реализацию с одним методом лямбдой?

Tags: java, java-8

Intllij Idea предлагает заменить анонимную реализацию с одним методом лямбдой. Но по смыслу это не функциональный интерфейс, а просто переопределение одного метода одного класса. Стоит ли заменять?

```
return new NextImportIdParams() {
    @Override
    public String getCollectionName() {
            return new CollectionName();            
    }
};
```

Comment: Лямбда - просто синтаксический сахар. Используйте то, что вам удобнее читать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все зависит от того под какую версию java пишете + от принятого code style.  Если вам никто не связывает руки, то определенно лямбы делают код более компактным и читабельным.

Answer (score 2):

В Java 8 можно любой анонимный класс, который реализует один абстрактный метод заменить на лямбду выражение, если анонимный класс реализует два абстрактных метода, то заменить на лямбду будет невозможно. Если вы проект перевели на Java 8, то такие измения безопасные. Idea дает возможность поменять все анонимные классы на лямбды.